# Polynomial and complex exercise.

Tags: polynomials, complex-numbers

Let $ f (x) = a_nx ^ n + a_ {n-1} x ^ {n-1} + \cdots + a_1x + a_0 $ be a polynomial in $ \mathbb C [x] $ of degree $ n $. Let $ c_1, c_2, \ldots, c_n \in \mathbb C $ be the $ n $ roots of $ f (x) $.

Show that for all $ k \in \{1,2, \ldots, n-1\} $ we have $$ \dfrac {a_ {n-k}} {a_n} = (- 1) ^ k \sum_ {i_1 = 1} ^ {n} \sum_ {i_2 = i_1 + 1} ^ {n} \ldots \sum_ {i_k = i_ {k-1} +1} ^ {n} \left (\prod_ {j = 1} ^ {k} c_ {i_j} \right) $$

My attempt is by induction on $ k $.

For $ k = 1 $ we must show that $$ \dfrac {a_ {n-1}} {a_n} = -\sum_ {i_1 = 1} ^ {n} c_ {i_1} $$.

To show this, notice that by fundamental theorem of algebra we have that the polynomial can be decomposed as $$ a_nx ^ n + a_ {n-1} x ^ {n-1} + \cdots + a_1x + a_0 = a_n (x-c_1) \cdots (x-c_n) $$ If we divide by $ a_n $, since clearly $ a_n \neq 0 $, we get the following $$ x ^ n + \dfrac {a_ {n-1}} {a_n} x ^ { n-1} + \cdots + \dfrac {a_0} {a_n} = (x-c_1) \cdots (x-c_n) $$
And mechanically obtain them then the following $$ x ^ n + \dfrac {a_ {n-1}} {a_n} x ^ {n-1} + \cdots + \dfrac {a_0} {a_n} = x ^ n- (c_1 + \cdots + c_n) x ^ {n-1} + \cdots \pm (c_1 \cdots c_n) $$ And by matching the terms we obtain that $$ \dfrac {a_ {n-1}} {a_n} = -(c_1 + \cdots + c_n) = - \sum_ {i_1 = 1} ^ {n} c_ {i_1} = (- 1) ^ 1 \sum_ {i_1 = 1} ^ {n} \left (\prod_ {j = 1} ^ {1} c_ {i_j} \right). $$

For the inductive step, suppose that it is true for $ k $ and let's see that it is true for $ k + 1 $, that is, we must show that $$\dfrac {a_ {n- (k + 1)}} {a_n} = (-1)^{k + 1} \sum_ {i_1 = 1} ^ {n} \sum_ {i_2 = i_1 + 1} ^ {n} \cdots \sum_ {i_ {k + 1} = i_ {k} +1} ^ {n} \left (\prod_ {j = 1} ^ {k + 1} c_ {i_j} \right) $$

For that, note that $$ \dfrac {a_ {n- (k + 1)}} {a_n} = \dfrac {a _ {(n-1) -k}} {a_n} = (- 1) ^ k \sum_ { i_1=1} ^ {n-1} \sum_ {i_2 = i_1 + 1} ^ {n-1} \cdots \sum_ {i_k = i_ {k-1} +1} ^ {n-1} \left (\prod_ {j = 1} ^ {k} c_ {i_j} \right) $$

I don't know how to get all the $ n-1 $ terms of the sequence to $ n $ in such a way that the $ k $ reaches $ k + 1 $, some help. My idea if it is ok or can it be done in another way?

Comment: Induction in this case is a red flag. But you have the right idea of using the fundamentalthm of algebra

Comment: How do I use the fundamental theorem of algebra to generalize that for any $ k $ between $ 1 $ and $ n-1 $.